# click listener on android widget Button not working

Tags: android, android-widget, onclicklistener

I'm working on an android project and created a widget for toggling Bluetooth (i.e., Pressing the widget turn on Bluetooth if turned off and vice versa). But the problem is that click listener of button is not working and when I click on the widget on the home screen it does nothing.
I do a lot of googling and tried almost all solutions but unfortunately nothing worked for me. I am unable to get the idea why my code is not working.

Here is the manifest file for project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gmail.redprince007.togglebluetooth" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".BluetoothToggle" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action                         android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/bluetooth_toggle_info" />
            </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And xml file for widget layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnToggleBluetooth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bluetooth_on" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And AppWidget-proviver.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/bluetooth_toggle"
android:initialLayout="@layout/bluetooth_toggle"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minWidth="40dp"
android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_icon"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard">

</appwidget-provider>
```

And BluetoothOnOff.Java Is:

```
public class BluetoothToggle extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothToggle";
    private final String toggleBluetoothAction = "ToggleBluetooth";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate()");
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetIds[i], intent, 0);

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.bluetooth_toggle);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnToggleBluetooth, pendingIntent);

            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEnabled()");
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDisabled()");
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateAppWidget()");
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.bluetooth_toggle);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your reply and help. I spend a day to resolve the issue but all my effort went in vain.

Comment: So finally I solve the problem after searching for two days. Here is the correct code: `Intent intent = new Intent(context, BluetoothToggle.class); intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
intent.putExtra(toggleBluetoothAction, toggleBluetoothAction);`
and did whatever I want to do in the `onReceive()`

Comment: write it as an answer, self explanatory kind of. Others might face the same problem.

Comment: @aB9 as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I solve the problem after searching for two days. Here is the correct code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, BluetoothToggle.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
intent.putExtra(AppWi‌​dgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
intent.putExtra(toggleBluetoothAction, toggleBluetoothAction);
```

And here is the `onReceive()` method which is called every time I clicked on the widget.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle != null && bundle.getString(toggleBluetoothAction) != null)
    {
        // My Logic
    }
}
```

Take a look at the `intent` `setAction` and `putExtra`, which are useful in my case to solve the problem. I checked many website but most of them didn't include this piece of code to make widget clickable. All they did is to create an `Intent` and then immediately create a `PendingIndent`. I did the same but nothing helped me in any way.

Thanks.